# Apposition mit Gedankenstrichen zwischen Verbteilen

Tags: subordinate-clause

> Doch dann stellte sich – nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen – heraus, dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird.*

Im obigen Beispiel befindet sich die Apposition ("nach einer [...]") zwischen "stellte sich" und "heraus", was mir, wenn solche seitliche Anmerkungen mit Atempause berücksichtigt werden sollten, ungünstig erschien. Ist das normal? Warum würde man in diesem Fall den Satz nicht so formulieren:

> 1. Doch dann stellte sich heraus – nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen – dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird.
> 2. Doch dann – nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen – stellte sich heraus, dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird.

**WirtschaftsWoche 13/23.3.2018 S. 22*

Comment: Das sind keine Bindestriche, sondern Gedankenstriche und auch keine Nebensätze, sondern Appositionen.

Comment: @tofro Alles klar, danke, ich habe die Frage dementsprechend bearbeitet.

Answer (score 3):

> Doch dann stellte sich – nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen – heraus, dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird.

Der Einschub *nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen* ist kein Nebensatz, sondern eine adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit. Die Gedankenstriche sind überflüssig, sie dienen nur der Hervorhebung. Die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder ist so wie sie ist gut.

> Doch dann stellte sich heraus – nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen – dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird.

Diese Variante braucht die Gedankenstriche, weil sie eine eigentlich unzulässige Reihenfolge der Satzglieder verwendet.

> Doch dann, nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen, stellte sich heraus, dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird.

Diese Variante funktioniert mit Kommas, notfalls mit Gedankenstrichen. In diesem Fall ist die gesamte adverbiale Bestimmung *nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen* das zweite Aufzählungsglied einer Liste, die von *dann,* angeführt wird.

Eine weitere Variante wäre:

> Doch dann stellte sich heraus, dass FGC zu 100 Prozent vom chinesischen Staat kontrolliert wird – nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen.

Der Unterschied zwischen all diesen Varianten liegt nur in der Betonung des abgesetzten Teils.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meinem Eindruck soll hervorgehoben werden, dass die Betriebsstrukturen derart verschachtelt waren, dass man den Eindruck gewinnen konnte, sie seien geradezu darauf angelegt gewesen, die wahren Besitzverhältnisse zu verschleiern. Einen gewissermaßen kontrastiven stilistischen Effekt kann man dadurch erzielen, dass man den Fluss des Obersatzes möglichst massiv durchbricht.

Würde ich versuchen, die angebotenen Sätze zu paraphrasieren und dabei die stilistischen Effekte so, wie sie sich mir darstellen, zu akzentuieren, käme ich auf folgende Möglichkeiten:

Ausgangssatz:

> Doch dann stellte sich - und zwar wohlgemerkt erst nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen - heraus, dass ...

oder

> Doch dann stellte sich - und dies (nicht mal eben so, sondern) erst nach einer aufwendigen Entwirrung der Beteiligungsstrukturen - heraus, dass ...

Satz 1:

> Doch dann stellte sich heraus, nachdem wir die Beteiligungsstrukturen aufwendig entwirrt hatten, dass ...

Satz 2:

> Doch dann, nämlich zu dem Zeitpunkt, an dem es gelungen war, die Beteiligungsstrukturen aufwendig zu entwirren, stellte sich heraus ...

Alle drei Sätze und weitere Varianten sind möglich. Der 'lahmste' ist wahrscheinlich Satz 1, indem er einfach eine Aufeinanderfolge verschiedener Ereignisse protokolliert. Satz 2 betont den Zeitpunkt, der Ausgangssatz betont die Tatsache und gewissermaßen den Knalleffekt des Untersuchungsergebnisses und wirkt spannungserzeugend. Ob es dazu der Ausklammerung in eine Parenthese mittels Gedankenstrichen bedarf? Vielleicht nicht.

Dies sind jedoch alles eher flüchtige stilistische Eindrücke meinerseits als handfest belegbare Regularitäten.